# Magento 1.14 : To add extra block inside order detail page

Tags: php

I want to place a link in order detail page. When clicked on it, it should add an extra parameter to

`/sales/order/view/order_id/xxx` url.

After that a separate `phtml` will be open in content.
I am FE developer and new on backend. Please provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

you should create new module with controller, and declarate your phtml in layout.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <sales_order_view_additional translate="label">
       <block type="core/template" name="additional" template="[Namespace]/[Modulename]/view.phtml"></block>
    </sales_order_view_additional>
</page>
```

read more about [how to create module](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/)

Comment: I am unable to add phtml from controller. I have created separate xml file in layout and added render method in controller action. But html is not appearing in front end.